# How to detect if element is not exist in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to scrapping the data from website.
Normally the website doesnot have the class "alert-block" and I can get

getElementById("project_status").innerText
getElementById("num-bids").innerText

But for some reason someone delete something then it have "alert-block"

So I Want to check

I have try

```
If appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("alert-block") Is Nothing Then '
            'Do task 1.
    else
    'do task 2
    enter code here
End if
```

But I failed

Comment: `If appIE.document.getElementsByClassName("alert-block").length = 0 Then 'Do task 1`

Comment: Can you tell me the way to check if 
getElementById("num-bids").
Doesnot exist.

Comment: `If IsNull(appIE.document.getElementById("num-bids")) Then 'Do task 1`